# Changing the inline style of a CDATA font tag via JavaScript

Tags: jquery, css, xml, cdata

I have an xml file that is loaded via jquery to populate a jQuery mobile list. Everything is working great except I need to change the inline styling of the font color on the `CDATA` font tag dynamically within the page.

I have tried `document.getElementById("font").style.color = "#000000";` and I have also tried to override the styling via the external CSS using `!important`.

Neither of those are working. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Of course `getElementById()` is never going to work as it only targets the `id` attribute of an element.  Can you just give `font` an `id` and target that instead?

Comment: Using jQuery it would simply be `$('#myID').css('color','#000');`

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Please mark my answer below as "accepted" by clicking the check-mark which will earn some reputation for both of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `getElementById()` is never going to work as it only targets the `id` attribute of an element. Can you just give `font` an `id` (like "myID") and target that instead?

```
document.getElementById("myID").style.color = "#000";
```

Or by using jQuery it would simply be `$('#myID').css('color','#000');`

---

As per comments, instead of using an `id`, targeting the element directly is just as valid...

```
$('font').css('color','#000');
```

Comment: Just to make this clearer, I didn't add an id to font, I just used your second answer: $('font').css('color','#000');

Comment: @Steph, yes, I was thinking about that but was focused on just fixing your original code... see updated answer.